# Relative links with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, seo

How can i convert all links within html to a relative links using .htaccess?

For example:
`http://www.mydomain.com/info.html` to `/info.html`

Comment: You can't (not with htaccess)

Answer (score 1):

.htaccess commands cannot change the content of your html files where those URLs live.

You will need to post process your html files on the server before they are sent to the client. How you do this depends on how you generate those html files.